# How big are soluted salts in drinking water?

Tags: everyday-life, water, diffusion, biology

I have just seen the TED talk [Michael Pritchard: How to make filthy water drinkable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXepkIWPhFQ) where a device called [LifeSaver bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LifeSaver_bottle) that filters particles that are bigger than 15nm out of water.

I have heard that it is unhealthy to drink distilled water because it is too pure. There are no soluted salts in that water and hence water diffuses into the cells to get an equal concentration of salts on both sides of the cell membran. As there is (almost) only water on the other side of the membran the water keeps flowing in until the cell "bursts".

So I wondered: Don't you get almost the same purity of water when you filter everything bigger than 15nm out? How big are soluted salts / chalk in water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you did was drink distilled water, it would not be terribly healthy for you. But most people eat as well - and that combination probably includes "healthy" minerals. Unless you binge-drink distilled water without any food, it's unlikely to cause serious health effects. Having said that - ions are pretty small - certainly smaller than 15 nm. But their charge may prevent them from going through the filter nonetheless - that depends on the construction of the filter, not just the "particle size" that it can filter out.